# Increasing time window for Munin alert and don't send alert immediately

Tags: munin

Let's say that I want to set load alert if load > 20 with Munin. However, Munin will immediately alert when the load spikes up to 20. Is it possible to adjust the alert integration time (time window), so that alert only triggers if load has stayed above 20 for 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not possible. Based on the chat with Munin community Munin does not support this and it must be done externally.

Here is a workaround I made by smoothing the load average values on the server side using a custom load monitoring plugin: http://opensourcehacker.com/2014/09/24/avoiding-load-average-spike-alerts-on-munin-monitoring/